# Trouble storing to Core Data via UIAlertAction

Tags: core-data, swift3

The idea is when a user clicks on the 'OK' option of the UIAlert, I want to save something to core data. However, I am getting the 'EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION' error as if the object is nil. The UIAlert will act as a confirmation before storing the data.

Whenever I get rid of the UIAlert and just store the data when the 'add data' button is pressed, everything works just fine. Any ideas?

Thanks

```
func createAlert(title: String, message: String)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    //create cancel action
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    //create ok action
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in print("OK")

    //error here....
        RestaurantController.storeOrder(name: self.tName.text!, address: self.tAddress.text!, vendor: self.tVendor.text!, price: Double(self.tPrice.text!)!, tip: Double(self.tTip.text!)!, delivFee: Double(self.tDelivFee.text!)!)

        self.tName.text = ""
        self.tAddress.text = ""
        self.tVendor.text = ""
        self.tPrice.text = ""
        self.tTip.text = "0"
        self.tDelivFee.text = "0"

    })

    alert.addAction(cancel)

    alert.addAction(ok)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: since your forcing an unwrap on all of your values in `RestaurantController.storeOrder`, are you sure that the values like `slef.tName.text!` and all the other ones you pass in actually have values?

Comment: Yes. This is what I do to ensure there are values:

    if (tName.text == "")
        {
            createAlert(title: "Additional input required", message: "Name field was left blank")
        }
        
        else if (tAddress.text == "")
        {
         ....
        }

I do this until every text box has been accounted for. Also sorry for poor format, first post on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like one of your strings are failing when being cast as a Double. Instead of force casting them, you should use a guard to ensure they are actually cast as a Double. You set tPrice.text to "" and that won't cast as a Double.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I implemented the guard statement and it ensures the app doesn't crash, however the code to save the data now never runs :\ I'm just confused how the data could become corrupt by a call to UIAlert...

Answer (score 0):

I obtained my end result by creating another parameter in the createAlert() function and passing in the order object after using a guard statement. Thanks for the suggestions.